# C# two functions called on one keyevent, ok but the first wait for the second to finish

Tags: c#, events, time, execute, keyeventargs

my first function fill a listbox with a string from a textbox, the second upload a file with ftp protocol.
 The two functions are called when i press the key Return and it works fine...but listbox is filled only when the second function has uploaded the file...ideas for first fill the listbox?? thanks

```
  private void invia(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (Alias != "Error:")
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                Scrivi();
                up();
            }
        }
```

Simple Solution:
cl4ptr4p suggest me to make a refresh,

```
private void invia(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (Alias != "Error:")
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
            {
                Scrivi();
                listBox1.Update();
                textBox1.Update();
                up();
            }
        }
```

However a better solution is a BackgroundWorker

Comment: Chances are, the box is being filled first, it's just not updating till the upload is done.

Comment: Smells like [parallel event handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415801/how-to-parallelize-event-handler-execution-in-c-sharp) is wanted

Comment: What version of .Net are you using? If it's .Net 4.5, I suggest using [await/async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx). If it's earlier than 4.5, I suggest using [BackgroundWorker()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the work in the background.

Comment: thanks CL4PTR4P adding a stupid line its works fine :)