# Implementing 2 EventHandlers at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, parallel-processing

Related to this thread:
[How to parallelize event handler execution in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415801/how-to-parallelize-event-handler-execution-in-c-sharp)

I'm working on a code-editor in winforms and I use both keyup and mousemove at a time for separate methods.

The problem was every time my mousemove event handler was Active, the keyup doesn't work or has conflict with each other.

I'm working on tooltip but separate functions.

For mousemove function was every time I hover an assigned keyword on richtextbox, tooltip will appear.

While in keyup, every time I type a keyword + "(" tooltip will appear.

So my question was how can I fix both event handlers and make it enable at a time, using system.threading or parallel.

Event used:

```
 private void rtb_CS_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){}    
 private void rtb_CS_KeyUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all i want to say that you should share your code if you want us to find the conflict in the code. second you need to expand the explanation of what went wrong in your application. i do not know what's the problem and when is it appearing. what do you mean "mousemove event handler was enable"? and so on.

now, for the answer itself. it is based only on what you wrote, so might be i'll delete it if you'll give more information:

when handling several event, and your handle might take more then several ticks, then you should create a thread that will handle the event:

```
private void rtb_CS_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Thread trd = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleMouseMove));
   trd.Start(e);
}  

private static void HandleMouseMove(object obj)
{
     // your handle
}
```