# 3rd Party SDK call in Parallel.Foreach loop handling events

Tags: c#, service, sdk, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm batching up items and processing them in parallel similarly to what is shown below. I need information not returned in the task that is sent through the two eventhandlers shown below (status updates). Can these be handled in a parallel foreach loop? I'm assuming that results would be stepping on each other setup the way it is currently? How to safely update the status in a SQL database table?

```
public function async task<junk> blahblahblah(List<items> unprocessedItems)
{          
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    Parallel.ForEach(unprocessedItems,  item =>
    {
        var exporter = new Exporter();
        exporter.ExportEnded += Exporter_ExportEnded;
        exporter.StatisticsReceived += Exporter_StatisticsReceived;
        var exporterTask = exporter.ExportAsync(cameraConfig, PlaybackMode.Sequential, fileName, true);

        //do exporter task stuff
        tasks.Add(exporterTask);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
    
private void Exporter_StatisticsReceived(object sender, StatisticsEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff with event information
    //update percent status in DB for each parallel row independently.
}
    
private void Exporter_ExportEnded(object sender, EndedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff with event information
    //log results in database.
}
```

Comment: Maybe here you'll find an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415801/how-to-parallelize-event-handler-execution-in-c-sharp

Comment: As a side note, to attract high quality answers it might a good idea to follow the C# naming conventions. Classes and methods in C# [are Pascal-cased](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). The `junk` and `blahblahblah` are not only unconventionally named, but they also convey aspirations for receiving low quality (junk and blah-blah) answers. I would suggest to edit your question and ensure that your C# code is valid, the C# conventions are followed, and the chosen names are meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm batching up items and processing them in parallel similarly to what is shown below.

The usage of `Parallel.ForEach` is incorrect. It calls `List<T>.Add` from multiple threads, and `Add` is not a threadsafe method. More broadly, it parallelizes object construction, adding a couple event handlers, starting the export (not the export itself), and adding an item to a list. The total amount of work being parallelized is practically nothing.

It would be more idiomatic to start all the exports one at a time, and then asynchronously wait for them all to complete:

```
var tasks = unprocessedItems.Select(item =>
{
  var exporter = new Exporter();
  exporter.ExportEnded += Exporter_ExportEnded;
  exporter.StatisticsReceived += Exporter_StatisticsReceived;
  return exporter.ExportAsync(cameraConfig, PlaybackMode.Sequential, fileName, true);
}).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

> I need information not returned in the task that is sent through the two eventhandlers shown below (status updates). Can these be handled in a parallel foreach loop?

I don't think that makes sense. The event handlers will already be coming in on thread pool threads, with multiple happening concurrently.

> How to safely update the status in a SQL database table?

The same way any other SQL update is done? SQL databases are comfortable with concurrency.

You will need to handle race conditions, such as `StatisticsReceived` invoked after `ExportEnded`. A properly-designed SQL statement should be able to handle that.